# Explanation of Perl code

Tags: perl

Can someone explain me what this:

```
$IN_OUT = ( $inOut eq 'out' ? 'Out' : 'In' );
```

is doing? I need to translate it to Java but I have no Idea about Perl.

Comment: Java translation: `String in_Out = "out".equals(inOut) ? "Out" : "In";`. Very tricky.

Comment: @Amadan: Double quotes needed in Java.

Comment: @choroba: See? Tricky! (I put them on `"out"`, then flubbed on the other two.)

Comment: It's the "ternary operator", like `if ($inOut eq 'out') { return 'Out' } else { return 'In' }`.

Comment: It is called ternary operator and works like: `CONDITION ? EVALUATE_IF_CONDITION_WAS_TRUE : EVALUATE_IF_CONDITION_WAS_FALSE`. You can assign the result of this to a variable.

Comment: @Sora pls. don't deface your post. It's a valid question and you got answers for it. Also consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) below, if you're satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a compact way of doing the same thing as:

```
if ( $inOut eq 'out' )
{
 $IN_OUT = 'Out';
} else
{
 $IN_OUT = 'In';
}
```

If `$inOut` is guaranteed to be only `out` or `in` the same result could be achieved simply by doing just:

```
$IN_OUT = ucfirst $inOut;
```

You can find a specific article on the Perl ternary operator here: https://perlmaven.com/the-ternary-operator-in-perl

Also, when in doubt about some Perl structure or operator you can start with these resources:

- https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html for all operators, and the ternary conditional one is at https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator
- https://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions.html for all internal functions
- https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html for all default internal Perl variables (which is often a point causing questions from people coming from other languages)
- the Perl FAQ qt https://learn.perl.org/faq/ should also be your first stop in case of problems